# Excel/VBA: Clear small values in columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a csv file which I want to transform. The problem is that the columns contain integers lower than 5000. In the columns are also identifiers, e.g. IE0034230957 and BLANK values. They should not change when applying the code.

The csv should open and produce a new file.

Could someone help me with a change in the code that works?

I read topics about this and could come to this code, however it doesn't work:

```
Sub RemoveSmallValues()

Dim myfilename As String
Dim myfilepath As String
Dim newfilename As String
Dim N As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim cellvalue As Long
Dim rng As Range, r As Range, lm As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

myfilepath = "Q:\Pre trade"
myfilename = "Snapshot_of_Model.csv"

Workbooks.Open (myfilepath)
Workbooks(myfilename).Activate 'Makes SnapShot.csv the active workbook

Set rng = Range("D:F")
lm = 5000

For Each r In rng
    If r.Value < lm Then
r.Clear
Next r

newfilename = "Q:\Snapshot_final.csv" 'new file path and file name without extension.

Workbooks(myfilename).SaveAs newfilename, FileFormat:=xlCSV 'Save the file with extension CSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close False 'Close the workbook without saving, as you have already saved the workbook with line before.

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens/not working?

Comment: Check because this doesn't seem to be  a valid file path: myfilepath = "Q:\Pre trade"

Comment: @Van you really need to post the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Off your question, I would code similarly like so

```
Sub t()

Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim c As Excel.Range

Set r = Range("a1").Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1)

For Each c In r.Cells
    If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
        If CDbl(c.Value) < 5000 Then c.Clear
    End If
Next c

Set r = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done using SQL and ADO.

```
Sub x()

Dim cnCSVConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim rstResults As ADODB.Recordset

Set cnCSVConnection = New ADODB.Connection
cnCSVConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=C:\Workspace\SW Pensions\RUFUS\;" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";"
'"C:\Workspace\"

cnCSVConnection.Open

Set rstResults = New ADODB.Recordset

rstResults.Open "Select [Entry-date],[Current value of policy]," & _
            "iif([Current value of policy]<100,1,0) from " & _
            "[Bonds Claims_WIP_TESTING.csv]", cnCSVConnection, adOpenKeyset

Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset rstResults

rstResults.Close
cnCSVConnection.Close

Set rstResults = Nothing
Set cnCSVConnection = Nothing

End Sub
```